# Do JASON internal actions work with Spring Autowire?

Tags: spring, artificial-intelligence, agents-jade, agents

I am developing an application using JADE, JASON (Agent frameworks) and Spring Boot. Basically what I have is a JADE Container where Both Jade and Jason Agents are registered in. And Since I am using Spring, I tend to Autowire services. In that case I am in need to access some services, inside some of my Jason internal actions (which I custom wrote extending DefaultInternalAction class). which seems not working. I have the idea how to Autowire and how the Beans work. My doubt is whether those internal actions are in the spring context or not. I guess they are not. Thats why may be the Autowire thing is not working. Can someone please explain me about the real action inside the jade container and internal actions so that I can think differently about using Autowire inside jason internal actions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, internal actions is created by jason, not spring that is why you cant autowire services. Personnaly, I create factory and use it for getting instance of a service. Something like this:

```
public class SpringPluginFactory {
    private static final SpringPluginFactory INSTANCE = new SpringPluginFactory();
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private SpringPluginFactory(){}

    private <T> T createPlugin(Class<T> iface) {
      if(applicationContext == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("applicationContext cannot be null");
      }
      try {
          return applicationContext.getBean(iface);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("factory unable to construct instance of " + iface.getName());
      }
  }

  public static <T> T getPlugin(Class<T> iface){
      return INSTANCE.createPlugin(iface);
  }

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }
```

}

then I create bean in order to set aplicationContext:

```
@Bean
public SpringPluginFactory pluginFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
    SpringPluginFactory pluginFactory = SpringPluginFactory.INSTANCE;
    pluginFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return pluginFactory;
}
```

and use the factory in any behaviours or internal actions

```
SpringPluginFactory.getPlugin(YouService.class).doSomething();
```

Maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks and I did the same before. But this is not completely Autowire thing. As in we are doing here a lookup in the spring context. I did the same but um feeling ugly. But no other option is there I guess to get this done.